# Creating files by means of pattern rules

Tags: makefile

Given this makefile:

```
foo_*.txt: foo_%.txt:
        echo "Foo number $*" > $@
```

I was hoping to be able to run, say, "make foo_22.txt" to create a file called "foo_22.txt".  Evidently, that is not the case: the result is the error "No rule to make target `foo_22.txt'."  If the file foo_22.txt does exist, I can get close to the desired behavior by running "make -B foo_22.txt".  How can I get to the desired behavior - namely, being able to run "make foo_22.txt" when the file "foo_22.txt" does not exist, resulting in creation of the file with the expected contents?

Comment: From where is `make` supposed to infer the number `22` when `foo_22.txt` doesn't exist?

Comment: Do you mean it always just comes from the command line? You want to make `foo_N.txt` for any `N`, where this always comes as special target via `make foo_N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo_%.txt:
    echo "Foo number $*" > $@
```